# Adding a custom page to a wordpress site

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress site. I want to add a new menu item and make it point to a custom page ( not the regular single post  page ) . This custom page will contain a contact us kind of form. How can I do this ? Is there a neat plugin do add the contact us kind of functionality as a widget ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the wordpress plugin "Fast Secure Contact Form". 
You can download it here: [Fast Secure Contact Form Download](http://wordpress.org/plugins/si-contact-form/)

If you need further instructions on how to use the plugin and/or how to add the menu item which links to the page, you can take a look at this (from screenshot #3):

[How to use screenshot](http://wordpress.org/plugins/si-contact-form/screenshots/)

Answer (score 0):

For custom page, You should create Template page in your theme folder.

[Page Template in Wordpress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates)

On the head of the custom page, You have to define page name as

`<?php
/*
Template Name: My Custom Page
*/ 
?>`

Below the code, You can write your code and activate page from dashboard

Go to your contact page > select your page template.

---

For contact form in wordpress. **Contact form 7** is standard plugin. If you want to use it in widget you have to install one more plugin (**Widget Contact Form 7**) after installing Contact Form 7.

[Contact Form 7](http://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-plugin/)

[Widget Contact Form 7](http://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-contact-form-7)